# Custom file renaming with Spring Integration Files

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I would like to add renaming features when moving files from one folder to another with custom renaming (for example a string, timestamp, etc.).

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582080/rename-file-in-place-using-spring-integration-filewritingmessagehandler) I am able to rename as follows:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = FILE_CHANNEL_SOURCE)
public MessageHandler moveFiles() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(processingDir));
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.FAIL);
    handler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    handler.setExpectReply(false);
    handler.setFileNameGenerator(processingFileNameGenerator());
    return handler;
}

@Bean
public DefaultFileNameGenerator processingFileNameGenerator() {
    DefaultFileNameGenerator defaultFileNameGenerator = new DefaultFileNameGenerator();
    defaultFileNameGenerator.setExpression("payload.name + '.processing'");
    return defaultFileNameGenerator;
}
```

But I would like to rename it like this:

```
@Bean
public DefaultFileNameGenerator processingFileNameGenerator() {
    DefaultFileNameGenerator defaultFileNameGenerator = new DefaultFileNameGenerator();

    String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Or any custom String here

    defaultFileNameGenerator.setExpression("payload.name" + timestamp);
    return defaultFileNameGenerator;
}
```

But the DefaultFileNameGenerator is not able to handle this 'expression', so how do we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer today and I hope you can find this code useful for anyone who's trying to achieve the same thing.

```
@Bean
public DefaultFileNameGenerator processingFileNameGenerator() {
    DefaultFileNameGenerator defaultFileNameGenerator = new DefaultFileNameGenerator();

    String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String expression = fileHelper.toExpression("payload.name + '.{}'", timestamp);

    defaultFileNameGenerator.setExpression(expression);
    return defaultFileNameGenerator;
}
```

FileHelper.class:

```
public class FileHelper {
    public String toExpression(String message, String... params){
        return MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(message, params).getMessage();
    }
}
```